# I have a main branch in VS code, but it doesn't appear on GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

[Here is an image showing the branches on VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49KY.png)
[Here is an image showing branches on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2jrp.png)

How can I resolve this? I would like everything to be on main. If I switch to the main branch on VS code, all my code dissapears. Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry if its a bad question. I'm just struggling here because I started this project natively on VS code and not github.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your branch into main. First, go back to your `main` branch and run the command `git merge austin-marraza`.